# Safari absolute positioned div disappear when scroll

Tags: css, scroll, safari, css-position

I have a sidebar that contains some products filters on an ecommerce website and has an absolute position. It works well on all browsers except for Safari on iPad and iPhone. It randomly disappears when the page scrolls.

I have tried to use the `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` trick as reported in many articles and other "tricks", but nothing works for me.

(iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay)

You can see the page at http://www.hardlyeverwornit.com/alexander-mcqueen

The sidebar is visible on mobile and iPad by clicking the `REFINE SEARCH` button. The class name is `new-search-results-filters`. At the moment I have removed the `tranlate3d ...` because it wasn't working.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a tour of the help centre to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also please read this: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Also as you have asked the exact same question previously, you should edit the other question to make it better rather than asking the same thing again as it will probably just receive the same amount of attention as the last one did

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any `resize` event to help you doing the position calculation? If yes, be aware that Safari has a identified bug that triggers the resize event randomly while doing scroll. This can mess up your position calculations.