# Elements disappear when scrolling in Safari - -webkit-transform fix only works the first time

Tags: mobile, scroll, safari, webkit, webkit-transform

This only happens in iPhone-sized Safari. I am aware that the "usual fix" for this issue is to apply -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); (per Serge's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271460/fixed-positioning-z-index-issue-in-mobile-safari?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) and that does fix the issue, but only once.

The issue occurs with a "drawer" menu that opens when the user clicks a menu button. The menu will show normally, but when it is touched/scrolled by a finger, the whole menu disappears from the page. Applying `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` fixes the issue, but only the first time. If the menu is closed and opened again, the issue reappears. I have confirmed that the `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` property is still on the meny (however it is grayed out in Safari developer tools- grayed out, not crossed out with a line going through it).

I added some JavaScript to the page so that when the menu is opened, it applies the -webkit-transform: translate3d... property to the menu, and while that does fix the issue permanently, I don't consider it clean enough to be a real fix.

I have also tried applying `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` in various combinations with `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` on the parent element, child elements, etc. and have not been able to fix the issue beyond the "first try".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So since this well-known Safari issue only occurs on elements with position: relative, I ended up fixing the issue by setting `position: fixed` on the scroll container element. No need to add `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` or `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`.

As mentioned in the question part, `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` fixed the issue, but only for the first time the menu was opened. Once it was closed and reopened without a page refresh, the issue would occur as though no fix was applied at all.

If you're dealing with this same issue, consider using `position: fixed`. If you're experiencing this issue with an element that is shown and hidden by the user (like a hamburger menu), you should be okay to set position: fixed on the parent scroll container that is shown when the user invokes it.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative for anyone else looking at this:

If you have any code within a jQuery `$( window ).on( "resize", function(){} );`, this can be fired on scroll. In my case I was hiding a menu when the window was resized, which worked fine on desktop, but it was also being called when scrolling in iOS Safari.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38977136/6619548) for pointing me towards this frustrating, well-hidden issue.